# How can I reduce my code when I used \addplot [black, mark = *] coordinates many times?

Tags: pgfplots

I am using `pgfplots` to drawing graph of the funtion `x^4 - 2 * x^2 + 2`. In my code, I used \addplot [black, mark = *] coordinates five times. How can I reduce my code?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
        domain=-3.5:3.5,
        ymin=-0.85,
        ymax=11,
        xmin=-3,
        xmax=3.5,
    samples=100,xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=2,unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
    width=11cm,
    grid=major,
    grid style={gray!30}
    ]
       \addplot [black, thick] {(x^4 - 2 * x^2 + 2};
       \addplot [black] coordinates {(-0.25, -0.25)}  node{$O$} {};
       \addplot[color=blue,dashed] coordinates {
            (-1, 0)
            (-1, 1)
            (1,1 )
            (1, 0)
        };
        \addplot[color=blue,dashed] coordinates {
        (-2, 0)
            (-2, 10)
            (2, 10)
            (2,0 )
                    };
        \addplot [black, mark = *] coordinates {( 0, 2)} ;
        \addplot [black, mark = *] coordinates {(-1, 1)} ;
        \addplot [black, mark = *] coordinates {(1, 1)} ;
         \addplot [black, mark = *] coordinates {(-2, 10)} ;
         \addplot [black, mark = *] coordinates {(2, 10)} ;

       \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Rmano pointed out, one `\addplot` command is enough, i.e.

```
\addplot [black, mark = *,only marks] coordinates {( 0, 2)(-1, 1)(1, 1)(-2, 10)(2, 10)} ;
```

Another option would be use the `samples at` key for `\addplot`, and let `pgfplots` calculate the y-values:

```
\addplot [black, mark=*,only marks,samples at={0,-1,1,-2,2}] {(x^4 - 2 * x^2 + 2};
```

If you want to shorten the code more, you can first declare a function with e.g.

```
declare function={Y(\x)=\x^4 - 2 * \x^2 + 2;}
```

and use `Y(x)` in the different `\addplot`s. You can also make the code drawing the dashed lines shorter using `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`.

Complete code, the output is the same as in your image:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
    declare function={Y(\x)=\x^4 - 2 * \x^2 + 2;},
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
        domain=-3.5:3.5,
        ymin=-0.85,
        ymax=11,
        xmin=-3,
        xmax=3.5,
    samples=100,xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=2,unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
    width=11cm,
    grid=major,
    grid style={gray!30}
    ]
       \addplot [black, thick] {Y(x)};
       \addplot [black, mark=*,only marks,samples at={0,-1,1,-2,2}] {Y(x)};
       \node at (axis cs:-0.25, -0.25) {$O$} ;

       \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2}{
       \draw [blue,dashed] (axis cs:-#1,0) |- (axis cs:#1,{Y(#1)}) -- (axis cs:#1,0);
       }

       \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, I learned another couple thing (the `samples at` and the `...foreach` thing). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm... quick'n'dirty --- define a command:

```
\newcommand\splat[1]{ \addplot [black, mark = *] coordinates{#1} }
```

And then

```
        \splat{( 0, 2)} ;
        \splat{(-1, 1)} ;
        \splat{(1, 1)} ;
        \splat {(-2, 10)} ;
        \splat {(2, 10)} ;
```

(millions of variations possible...)

Or in this case you can just use the `only marks` keyword:

```
\addplot [black, mark = *, only marks ] coordinates { ( 0, 2)
        (-1, 1)
        (1, 1)
        (-2, 10)
        (2, 10)};
```